# Angular 8 and asp.net mvc routing is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, angular8

I am new to the Angular 8 with asp.net mvc.
Facing issue with routing,

(1) Application home url: http://localhost/dashboard
it has all details with some model numbers in bootstrap table, when click on model number with group name it will route to https://localhost/dashboard details?Groupname=xyz&ModelNo=2300 this works fine.

(2) At this stage everything is good but when refresh the browser error is getting displaying
as,

**This localhost page can't be found**
**No webpage was found for the web address https://localhost/dashboard details?Groupname=xyz&ModelNo=2300**
HTTP ERROR 404

What I tried
(1) added location strategy and hash strategy- didn't worked
when added this on refresh IIS windows was getting displayed.

(2) used url rewrite same error displayed HTTP ERROR 404.

Need assistance to solve this problem

Comment: Anybody, let me know if any more details required to understand or need clarification.

Comment: Please add more details to your question, like current code and error details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution by spending almost 3 days, need to change base href,
Got the hint from
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11046.